# Getting Friends Lists

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app lets user post on each others wall. Till now we were using v1.0 of facebook to do so where in me/friends would give the whole list of friends. Now when switching to 2.2 we found that the same api is giving only the friends that have logged in to our app. So we thought of using the taggable_friends api. The question is Can we use the Id given by taggable_friends to POST a Feed on that users wall?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can´t use anything to post to the wall of a friend, you can only post to the wall of an authorized user and you need `publish_actions` for that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed

See the "Publishing" sections. Keep in mind that you will have to go through the review process with `publish_actions` if you want it to work after April 2015: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

`taggable_friends` will only get approved by Facebook for tagging, not just to get a list of friends for anything else. After all you only get a tagging token anyway.

This is important about sharing in general: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/share

For further assistance, it would be needed to know how exactly you post on the walls right now.

Comment: Is it possible that I can post on the users wall and the post is only visible to his friends? Or Can I use the Fb.dialog and send a private message to all his friends?

Comment: that depends on the settings of the user, i guess. he can set and change the visibility.

Comment: and this is what you can use to send a message to his friends: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog/ - but of course you can´t control it, you are not allowed to send ANY message, the user decides what to send. everything else would be pure spam.

Comment: you can also not preselect more than 1 friend in the "to" parameter btw.